# Unexpected assignment within function to variables in namespace in python using +=

Tags: python, list

This a purely methodological question. I have a basic function, and it is unexpectedly appending values to a list I created. I know that `.append()` and `.extend()` mutate the list object in-place, but my particular issue is with `+=`.

I was under the impression that `x+=y` was the same as `x = x+y` but this is not the case in a function, where I am finding that it overwrites local variables defined externally to the function.

Allow me to illustrate:

```
def test1(lst):
    lst += ['new element']
    return 'something else'

def test2(lst):
    lst = lst + ['new element']
    return 'something else'

# Testing them
lst = ['a','sample','list']
test1(lst)
print('test1 returns the following:',lst)

lst = ['a','sample','list']
test2(lst)
print('test2 returns the following:',lst)
```

This returns

```
test1 returns the following: ['a', 'sample', 'list', 'new element']
test2 returns the following: ['a', 'sample', 'list']
```

Of course, if you change the names of the variables, then it doesn't do this. But this fundamentally changes my understanding of variables defined within functions as opposed to locally and may have some serious implications for my coding behavior. Can someone clearly explain what is going on?

Comment: " I know that .append() and .extend() overwrite variables in the namespace" no, they do not. They mutate the list object in-place, which is what `+=` does. Mutating an object and overwriting a variable are *two completely different things*. Also: "I was under the impression that x+=y was the same as x = x+y" nope. The augmented assignment operators should *mutate the objects if the objects are mutable*, so it will mutate list objects, but not int objects (of course, since int objects are not mutable). Anyway, you should really read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: `x += y` is implemented as `x = x.__iadd__(y)`; whether that is equivalent to `x = x.__add__(y)` (i.e., `x = x + y`) depends on the definition of `x.__iadd__`.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for the reference. I have updated my question to clear up the language I used to be more precise (even though I think you know what i meant). As an aside, I've been programming in python for many years, and it is not uncommon for people to use x+=y and x = x+y interchangeably, hence my confusion.

Comment: Given your question title it is not clear to me you grok the distinction between mutating an object and assigning to a variable, in any case, the augmented assignment operators [were added to the language](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/) for the expressed purpose of providing a mutating operator, so from the linked PEP: "They implement the same operator as their normal binary form, except that the operation is done in-place when the left-hand side object supports it, and that the left-hand side is only evaluated once."

Comment: Also note: "Of course, if you change the names of the variables, then it doesn't do this." isn't true.

Comment: i changed the question title to make it more searchable to people with this same problem. I fully comprehend the answer, and have read the post you sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of course, if you change the names of the variables, then it doesn't do this.

That isn't true. Observe:

```
def test1(foo):
    foo += ['new element']

def test2(foo):
    foo = foo + ['new element']

lst = ['a','sample','list']
test2(lst)   # lst stays the same
test1(lst)   # lst gets changed
```

In both cases, we bind `foo` to the list otherwise known as `lst`. In `test2`, we assign to the local name `foo` the result of adding this list to a list containing the `'new element'`.

In `test1`, we modify the list in-place using the `+=` operator.

---

> I was under the impression that `x+=y` was the same as `x = x+y`

That is not true, but there's a kernel of truth in it: When `__iadd__` is not defined on the type of `x`, Python defaults to performing `x = x + y` instead. In addition, even when you only use augmented assignment operators (such as `+=`) within a function, the compiler will mark that name as local (`STORE`/`LOAD_FAST`).